# How do I remove all these tris in this area?

Tags: vertices

I have this model

[image]

And I want to remove all the tris in the middle to reduce the count and keep it flat
[image]

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I am sorry but I see no triangles. Could you elaborate and explain more what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

We can't see any tris, but if you're talking about reducing the amount of quads from 6 to 2 you can do it this way:

[image]

First select this edge and push it:

[image]

Join the opposite vertices:

[image]

Dissolve the vertical edges:

[image]

Then push these edges:

[image]

And again join and dissolve:

[image]

[image]

You can even end up with 1 quad if your topology allows you (you need to dissolve an horizontal edge on the left or on the right):

[image]

Comment: I love how you explained step by step. Topology guides just show the end result and it makes creating them without ruining your shape difficult.

Comment: thanks, that's the way I've found, but there may be others  ;)

Comment: I'm not French but I subscribed to your channel. Using auto-translate, the tuts are *followable*

Comment: Hey thanks for the support, I'm not sure you can trust the translation, it seems whimsical from what I saw, learn french instead aha  ;)